# How to search for object in Dictionary with SearchBar TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I am using a Dictionary for TableView. I also have a search bar for searching an item in the table.

The data is stored as following:

```
var namesDic = [String: [Name]]()
```

And I search through it as:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
        filteredNames = namesDic
    } else {
        filteredNames.removeAll()
        for persons in namesDic {
            let person = persons.value.filter { $0.getName().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!)
            }
            for boy in person {
                filteredNames[String(describing: boy.getName().characters.first!)] = [boy]
            }
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Problem: I only get one record now when I search for an item.

Is there a better way to implement above?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you should perform append to resulted array of values. But you are assigning value. filteredNames[String(describing: boy.getName().characters.first!)] = [boy]

Comment: @DJ-Glock Thanks for the hint. I have to remove only values first and then apply appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More lines of code but it is working now. I stored  **values** from dictionary in different variable and filtered those. The filtered **values** stored in the another variable and then iterate through.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
        filteredNames = namesDic
    } else {
        filteredNames.removeAll()

        var namesArray = [Name]()

        for (_, value) in namesDic {
            namesArray += value
        }

        let namesFilteredArray = namesArray.filter { $0.getName().lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())
        }

        for filteredName in namesFilteredArray {
            if let letter = filteredName.getName().characters.first {
                if filteredNames[String(letter)] != nil {
                    filteredNames[String(letter)]?.append(filteredName)
                } else {
                    filteredNames[String(letter)] = [filteredName]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```